# Javascript? Load something after Page load

Tags: javascript

I am not good at Javascript so I have no clue. However, I would like to have a div load in the body after the page has loaded.

At the minute the page takes a while to load because it is loading php that is sorting an array with json data with each entry from a database. (if that makes sense) So this is causing the page's load to increase.

Because of this I would like to let the page load first and then the array list as atm it is just staying on a white loading screen until it has all loaded which makes my site look slow.

Comment: So have you tried anything? Have any code to share so we can base answers off of that?

Answer (score 2):

Your need use AJAX (`XMLHttpRequest`) and DOM manipulation (`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/your_slow_sort_array.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp

Note : With [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) you can simplify your life

Comment: This part is the most useful information: `Note : With Jquery you can simplify your life`. :) I call it a crutch, but its far better than learning the evil bowels of javascript itself... especially with ajax calls!

Comment: @Randall come on its not that evil :) difficult yes, but has its own fun :)

Comment: Ever since jquery came about, I got lazy and wild with js on pages haha. Its 'that good' of a framework to use. When I have to do raw js, I scream and die a little inside ;)